Why does it seem like Jurin's Law contradict how capillary action works?
Okay, so Jurin's Law relates surface tension, $\gamma$, with the rise height of the water, $h$:
$$h = \frac{2 \gamma \cos \theta}{\rho rg}.$$
This means that, as surface tension increase, $h$ will increase as well.
However, looking deeper into how capillary action works, it seemed that the height rise depends on cohesive (which has a positive correlation with surface tension) and adhesive forces - if adhesive forces increase (for instance, between glass and water), the water is more effectively drawn up, which increase $h$. Conversely, if cohesive forces are greater than adhesive forces, then the liquid in the tube will "sink" instead of rise. So if we increase cohesive forces, it means that $h$ will decrease.
This seems to suggest that surface tension and $h$ are negatively related, that is, increasing surface tension decreases $h$, which contradicts Jurin's Law.
Could someone explain this? Is there a mistake in my reasoning? Thank you.

Can you explain in more detail your statement "Conversely, if cohesive forces are greater than adhesive forces, then the liquid in the tube will "sink" instead of rise."?

For instance in the case of mercury in a glass capillary tube. Mercury has higher cohesive forces with other mercury molecules, while it does not adhere very well to glass. So its cohesive forces are greater than its adhesive forces, and the liquid will appear to "sink" instead of rising in the capillary tube.

In that case, doesn’t the contact angle cause the cosine term to be negative, so the magnitude of the height change still scales with the surface tension (and cohesion)?
